# Closing a panel with animation using __doPostBack

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, custom-controls, extension-methods

I have a Custom User Control that will display messages to the user ie. Information, Error, Success. This is based off of [Clickable Panel Closure](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2009/05/14/Implementing-IPostBackEventHandler-in-an-ASPNET-Control.aspx) I would like to add animation to the closing of the message using jquery but I am not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions? Outside of the controls being displayed my project is almost identical to the one in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your own JS function and do the animations inside it. Then call the __doPostBack. Make sure to postback **after** the animation is done.

E.g:

Javascript:

```
function my__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    my_PanelAnimateFunction(function() { 
        __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument);
    });
}

function my_PanelAnimateFunction(callback) {
    //do animation stuff
    doAnimation();

    //callback so that the __doPostBack is executed
    callback(); 
}
```

Codebehind:

```
var script = String.Format("my__doPostBack('{0}', '');", myPanel.ClientID);
myPanel.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, script);
```